# Can an expression of Matrix Multiplication involving more than one value evaluate to a single value?

Tags: matrices, neural-networks

I've been following an article on how Neural Networks work. In the article it goes over the math step by step to develop one.

This is the article in question:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/05/neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-and-r/

I've been following a long in Excel. On Step 10 I am stumped. The formula reads:

wout = wout + matrix_dot_product(hiddenlayer_activations.Transpose, d_output)*learning_rate

Where Matrix_dot_Product() is a function for multiplying matrices. These are the two matrices.
$$\begin{pmatrix} .814 & .916 & .814\end{pmatrix}$$ 
$$\begin{pmatrix} .035\\\ .032\\\ -.13 \end{pmatrix}$$

Wout = .3 and learning rate = .1.

Sorry I cant seem to figure out how to properly express this using MathJax, other than the first formula I posted.

When implementing this in Excel I found that it evaluates to a single value? I thought that because there is matrix multiplication involved, it would evaluate to a matrix, but it doesn't.

Why is this?

Comment: Hints: What are the sizes of the matrices involved?  (number of rows, number of columns)  What is the definition of `matrix_dot_product` ?

Comment: When I scroll down to the excel part of the paper, it appears as though (in orange) `hiddenlayer_activations.Transpose` is a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: @MattCremeens, yes it is a 3x3 matrix. To get what the author had for Wout in that step, I had to calculate the posted equation for each value in Wout, on each column of hiddenlayer_activations. Hence the reason I only posted a 1x3 matrix (transformed 1st column of hiddenlayer_activations). Maybe I'm not approaching the problem correctly, but that's the only way I know how to do it.

Comment: `wout` should be a 3x1 vector after you multiply a 3x3 matrix by a 3x1 vector. `d_output` is a 3x1 vector. Does that help?

Comment: Actually that does help. It appears I've been "adding" matrices improperly in Excel. Without assigning a Named Range to them and using that in the formula, it won't actually add the matrix. Thank you though, your comment made me realize that I must be doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a matrix $A$, which is $M\times N$ ($M$ rows, $N$ columns), and a matrix $B$, which is $K\times L$.

Then you can **only** perform the matrix multiplication $C=AB\,$ **if** $\,N=K$. If so, then $C=AB$ is $M\times L$. I.e., $$ \underbrace{C}_{M\times L} = \underbrace{A}_{M\times N}\, \underbrace{B}_{K\times L} \;\;\;\text{   if}\;\;\;\; N\equiv K $$
One special case is when $N=K$, $M=1$, $L=1$, in which $$C=AB=(a_1,\ldots,a_N)(b_1,\ldots,b_N)^T = (a_1,\ldots,a_N)\begin{pmatrix}b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_N\end{pmatrix} = \sum_ja_jb_j$$ so this particular matrix multiplication is *just the vector dot product*. (Meaning $C$ is $1\times 1$, i.e. $C\in\mathbb{R}$).

On the other hand, we get the *outer product* when $N=K=1$, which produces a matrix from two 1D matrices (i.e., vectors).